# How can i pivot my Mysql result

Tags: mysql

I have four tables named `tbl_attribute`, `tbl_attribute_value`, `tbl_product_attr_value`

Please find my sql schema

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_attribute_value` (
  `attr_value_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `attr_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `value` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_attribute_name` (
  `id` int(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `attribute_name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

  CREATE TABLE `tbl_product_attribute_value` (
  `product_attr_val_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `attribute_value_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `independent_values` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sequence` int(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f35c (no data)
```

What i trying to do is just pivoting the current result as

```
product_id| (attribute_name)Film |(attribute_name)Year
```

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't show any data and is a waste of a fiddle. You could have put the schema in your question.

Comment: Without data there simply is no value added by the sqlfiddle and it is easier to read your question with all facts in one place. Please show us the `current query` and the `current result`.

Comment: @solan Thrasher Please find a corrected fiddle on [link ]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/737378/4

Comment: Edit your question accordingly

Comment: My question is same how could i pivot my current result.